# 'created at' and 'updated at' fields

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This seems like a really simple one but I'm struggling to figure it out. I want a column in my database that lists when a record was first created and another column that says when it was updated. It's my understanding I should be able to do all this just using MySQL. All help is appreciated :)

This stinks still no answer, reasons I'm already starting to miss Ruby on Rails...

Comment: pls elobrate your question, I dont find anything clear.

Comment: mdgrech wants to add two fields that contain the timestamp of when the table row was created, and when it has been updated.

Comment: +1 seems pretty clear to me

Comment: mdgrech you will have to use the php time with a DATETIME field for the created column which will be populated by your code and a timestamp field on your updated column that will be DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP so you won't have to update this 2nd field and only workout the first field on creation of the data

Answer (score 7):

You will probably need to use a combination of the `Datetime` datatype and the `Timestamp` data type.  I would set my `created` column as a `DateTime` with a `DEFAULT NOW()`, and my `updated` column as a `Timestamp` with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and an `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attribute.

Here are the docs for the `Timestamp` dt:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

> In a CREATE TABLE statement, the first TIMESTAMP column can be declared in any of the following ways:
>
> With both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses, the column has the current timestamp for its default value, and is automatically updated.
>
> With neither DEFAULT nor ON UPDATE clauses, it is the same as DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
>
> With a DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clause and no ON UPDATE clause, the column has the current timestamp for its default value but is not automatically updated.
>
> With no DEFAULT clause and with an ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clause, the column has a default of 0 and is automatically updated.
>
> With a constant DEFAULT value, the column has the given default and is not automatically initialized to the current timestamp. If the column also has an ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clause, it is automatically updated; otherwise, it has a constant default and is not automatically updated.

Comment: From what i know you can't use both at once... if you have a field with DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP you cannot have an ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP event. `#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause `

Comment: +1: Correct approach - add two columns & set the DEFAULT constraint appropriately.

Comment: sorry to let you down again but Datetime field does not accept default NOW() aswell... http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27645

Comment: so has anyone figured this out yet cause I'm still stumped :/

Answer (score 1):

To fulfill your question and for others viewing this question, here is the answer.  Note this was written for MySQL 5.x.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test1`;
CREATE  TABLE `test1` (
  `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
  `created` DATETIME ,
  `updated` DATETIME ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX (`name`)
);

DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test1_created`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `test1_created` BEFORE INSERT ON `test1` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      SET NEW.`created` = UTC_TIMESTAMP();
      SET NEW.`updated` = UTC_TIMESTAMP();
    END;
$$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test1_updated`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `test1_updated` BEFORE UPDATE ON `test1` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      SET NEW.`updated` = UTC_TIMESTAMP();
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Note**

You could use TIMESTAMP for the `updated` column which would have automatically updated the value thus not requiring the BEFORE UPDATE trigger, however TIMESTAMP has a range from 1970 to 2038 which is fast approaching and I like to think my applications will live forever :). Although TIMESTAMP is only 4bytes while DATETIME is 8bytes.

`TIMESTAMP range '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC`

`DATETIME range '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'`

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL 5.0 Certification Guide:

```
CREATE TABLE ts_test5 (
  created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0,
  updated TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  data CHAR(30)
);
```

> To control the initialization and update behaviour of a TIMESTAMP column, you add either or both of the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attributes to the column defintion when creating the table with CREATE TABLE...
>   and
>   ...if you do not specify either of the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attributes when creating a table, MySQL automatically assigns BOTH to the first TIMESTAMP column

Also

> you cannot use DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with one column and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with another

Comment: Also, even if you set a table up this way and then you insert a new row from phpMyAdmin and you don't specify the current_timestamp function the times will be zero timestamps. You need to specify current_timestamp on adding rows from phpMyAdmin. However, SQL inserts and updates will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the timestamp fields with default attributes that Paul W has suggested, you can use AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE triggers to populate the fields.

Comment: he can use only 1 timestamp field that will auto populate itself using mysql, the second would need to be  filled by php.

Answer (score 0):

> You will need two fields "Created" and
>   "Updated" with type datetime. When a
>   new entry is inserted then insert
>   "Created" with current time stamp.
>   When a update is happening insert
>   "Updated" with the current time stamp,
>   and let the "Created" field remain as
>   it is.
>
> For current time stamp you can use
>   NOW() in your mysql query.